# How to retain cmake changes when building Docker image in Google Cloud Build?

Tags: docker, makefile, cmake, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

I am working on a CI pipeline with Google Cloud Build to run tests on code stored in Cloud Source Repositories. As it stands, the pipeline uses the docker cloud builder to build an image with `docker build`. The building process takes nearly an hour to complete and it runs periodically. It builds the program and then runs a single test on it in one build step, this part works fine. What I want to do is build the program using `cmake` and `make` then store the image in the container registry so that I can run future tests from that image without having to spend the time building it before testing.

The issue is that when I run the custom image from the Container Registry in Cloud Build, it does not recognize the module that was built with `cmake`. The pipeline ran tests just fine when I built it then ran tests in the same build steps, but no longer recognizes the module when I run the image as a custom builder on Cloud Build.

The dockerfile used to build the image is as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3.7
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip3 install numpy
RUN pip3 install matplotlib
RUN pip3 install transitions
RUN pip3 install pandas
RUN apt-get install -y cmake
RUN apt-get install -y swig
RUN pip3 install conan
RUN ln -s ~/.local/bin/conan /usr/bin/conan
RUN apt-get install gcc

RUN cd ~
RUN python3 path/to/master_build.py
```

The `master_build.py` uses os.system commands to build the program. It calls a shell script to do the cmake process. The shell script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir dist3
cd dist3
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../src
make
cd ~
```

This builds the program no problem, then the python script calls other scripts to run basic tests, which all work fine when I do it in this build step. The issue is, when I use Cloud Build to run the custom image from container registry, it can no longer find the module that was built with CMake.

This is the cloudbuild config file that runs the custom image:

```
steps:
    - name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/built_images:latest'
      args: ['python3', 'path/to/run_tests.py']
```

I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`, which is weird because it worked fine when I ran the test script in the same build after calling `cmake`. I'm guessing that the file system is not being retained when I push the image to container registry and it can no longer find the dist3 folder.

How can I retain the dist3 folder when I am pushing the image to container registry?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please indicate the name and make sure you have all libraries needed in your Dockerfile? Just for your info this doc [1] describes how to store images at Container Registry and this doc [2] describes how to run the image to test it works as expected. 

[1] https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/building/build-containers#storing_images_in
[2] https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/building/build-containers#run_the_docker_image